# How to run multiple cucumber tests side by side

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, automated-tests, watir

I'm trying to test my multiplayer web game, and I need to run 2 instances of the game at once, and I'm unsure how to run them both in seperate browsers at the same time. He's my code for the test;

```
When(/^I navigate to the multiplayer game page$/) do

When (/^I click to play game$/) do

  play = @browser.iframe(:id , 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').button(:id , 'play_game_form_button')
    Watir::Wait.for_condition(10 , 2 , "Waiting to see play button") {
      puts play.present?
    }
    play.click
end
    play.click
end
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create two browsers or how to manage them in your Cucumber framework? You can create two browser instances by initializing two browser instances - ie `@browser1 = Watir::Browser.new; @browser2 = Watir::Browser.new`. How you manage in that steps might depend on how you want your steps to read.

Comment: Hi Justin, I can open 2 browsers with watir, but I'm not sure how I can run the same test in both of the browsers when they are open.

Comment: @Ethranes Maybe you identify which player is acting in each step. I think you could parameterize that to keep it dry.